# Convert to binary with loop displays only the numbers, not binary

Tags: java

the idea is that the program will show numbers and their binary equivalent but it is showing only the numbers and one binary on the end,what is wrong

```
public class Convert {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        for (number = 0; number < 4095; number++) {
            System.out.println("Number is :" + number);
        }
        System.out.print("Convert to binary is:");
        System.out.print(binaryform(number));
    }

    private static Object binaryform(int number) {
        int remainder;
        if (number <= 1) {
            System.out.print(number);
            return null;
        }
        remainder = number % 2;
        binaryform(number >> 1);
        System.out.print(remainder); {
        }
        return remainder;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using your own binary calculation when there is a built in lib?

Comment: how to go there?in this lab.

Comment: @Dan4o He means the method suggested by user000001: Using the pre-defined method `Integer.toBinaryString(number)` instead of defining your own method `binaryForm(number)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
Integer.toBinaryString(number));
```

Answer (score 1):

change it as below

```
for(number=0;number<4095;number++){

System.out.println("Number is :"+ number);
System.out.print("Convert to binary is:");
System.out.print(binaryform(number));
}
```

Comment: because in the for loop you should do whatever you want for each number.at the end of the loop the number will be 4095 and it will exit the loop.so the binary was printed for you is for 4095

Comment: The code works but starts around 2500,not from 0,what is wrong now?And the binary is 13 numbers ,but they supposed to be 12...........

Comment: @Dan4o It does start at 0. However, it most likely shows the x most recent lines only, to save memory. Also, your `binaryForm` method is wrong.

Comment: @Dan4o it is because of memory leak or a lack of execution memory.You can write it to a file and checked or just increase the memory and test.If you change the number in the loop from 4095 to 200 then you will see that it is printing from 0

Comment: @Dan4o Integer.toBinaryString(number)) is ok

Answer (score 0):

In here:

```
System.out.print("Convert to binary is:");
```

you are *not* in the `for` loop, so that it will only print out the numbers and just the last number's binary equivalent.